# real-time printing to console with R in jupyter

Tags: r, jupyter, output-buffering

Using an R GUI or just R from a command line, this code results in integers being printed 0.2 seconds apart.

In contrast when I use R in a jupyter notebook, all of the printing happens only after the loop is complete.

```
for(x in 1:10){
    print(x)
    Sys.sleep(0.2)
}
```

I tried to force real-time printing inside of Jupyter with

```
for(x in 1:10){
    print(x)
    flush.console()
    Sys.sleep(0.2)
}
```

...to no effect.  The results were the same -- printing from within a for loop in jupyter always seems to be delayed until after the loop.

Is there a way to ensure the notebook outputs the results of print statements in a real time way?

Comment: this is prbly worth posting an issue on [`IRKernel`](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel). There are hacks for it in python but not R.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I did file an issue.  Afterwards, I found an [interesting related issue](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/295) that recommends using `message()` instead of print.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently, the only way to "trigger" processing of printed output is either using `message("text")` (instead of `print("text")` or `cat("text")`) or not writing it into the loop but in a statement of it's own.

The underlying problem is in https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/3 and a proposed fix is in https://github.com/hadley/evaluate/pull/62 -> It needs a change in `evaluate` to allow `flush.console()` and friends to work. The gist of the problem: we use `evaluate` to execute the code and evaluate process the output one statement at a time and handles the output **after** the statement completes. Unfortunately, in this case, a for-loop is just one statement (as is everything in `{...}` blocks), so printed output only appears in the client after the for-loop is done.

A workaround is using the `IRdisplay` package and the `display_...()` functions instead of `print()/cat()` (or [plots](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/295)...). But this needs full control over the printed stuff: It's either everything is using print (and it gets delayed until after the complete statement is finished) or nothing should print (or plot) in that statement. If a called functions prints something, the output would be in the wrong order (`{print("a"); display_text("b"); print("c")}` would end up as `b a c`). Using `capture.output()` might get you around this limitation, if you really have to... If you use plots, there [are currently no workarounds](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/295) apart from writing the plot to disc and sending it via `display_png(..)` and friends.

Comment: Thanks.  It would be a "nice-to-have" to get this fixed but probably the most common use case is simply adding debugging or tracking statements to code blocks that are actively under development or that take a long time to run.  For that use, `message()` works just fine.  Getting plots to display in a certain order seems like a much less commonly-needed thing.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue any more. The following code works in jupterLab now

```
for(x in 1:10){
    print(x)
    flush.console()
    Sys.sleep(0.2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

R version of the answer for Python [Flush output in for loop in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150097/flush-output-in-for-loop-in-jupyter-notebook) works for me:

```
cat(paste0('Your text', '\r'))
```

Apparently `\r` will trigger a flush.

Comment: This is not correct, consider `(\(){cat(paste0('Your text', '\r'));Sys.sleep(3)})()` where `Your text` is only printed after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Jan Katins presented the relevant issue that has been resolved by now as David Chen writes.

For scenarios where foreign packages eventually rely on the function `base::print()` to continuously relay information, one could use `trace()` to flush after every `print()`:

```r
trace(what = "print", where = getNamespace("base"), exit = flush.console, print = FALSE)
```