# Flush output in for loop in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, flush

I want to print out `i` in my iteration on Jupyter notebook and flush it out. After the next iteration, I'll print the next `i`. I tried solutions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343688/how-to-flush-the-printed-statements-in-ipython), however, it just print out `0123...9` without flushing the output for me. Here is my working code:

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i)) # or print(i, flush=True) ?
    time.sleep(0.5)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

these are my setup: **ipython** 5.1, **python** 3.6. Maybe, I missed something in the previous solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#Try this:
import sys
import time

for i in range (10):  
    sys.stdout.write('\r'+str(i))
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

## '\r' will print at the beginning of the line

Comment: thanks! this solution works for me. seems like we don't really need flush output at all.

Answer (score 10):

The first answer is correct but you don't need `sys` package. You can use the `end` parameter of the `print` function. It specifies what to print at the end, and its default value is `\n`(newline) ([docs1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), [docs2](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp)). **Use `\r`(carriage return) instead.**

```
import time

for i in range (10):  
    print(i, end="\r")
    time.sleep(0.5) # This line is to see if it's working or not
```

Comment: Thanks @Alperen! This one is actually handy!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
for i in range (10):  
    print("\r", end=str(i))
```